# How can I access the last values of states within a hook that provides debouncing functionality in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, debouncing

I have got a hook that provides debouncing the functions. But I can't access the last values of States in it. If I add to dependencies, It will break debouncing structure. What should I do ?

```
const debouncedCreate = useRef(
  debounce(async (data) => {
    try {
      ...
      const result = await dispatch(createMachineGroup(data)).unwrap();
      ...
    } catch (error) {
      ...
      // memoizedMachineGroupsErrorIndicator is fetching last value of state errors.
      // it is working outside of debounce func.
      // but inside, it fetchs last value before debounced function.
      if (isset(() => memoizedMachineGroupsErrorIndicator)) {
         ...
      }
    }
  }, 300),
).current;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `useRef` trick you can use.

```
 const stateRef = useRef()
 stateRef.current = memoizedMachineGroupsErrorIndicator
 const debouncedCreate = useRef(
      debounce(async (data) => {
        try {
          ...
          const result = await dispatch(createMachineGroup(data)).unwrap();
          ...
        } catch (error) {
          ...

          if (isset(() => stateRef.current)) {  // here you will always get the last value
             ...
          }
        }
      }, 300),
  ).current;
```

The callback memoizes the reference of `stateRef`. Its reference is always same. Just the `current` property changes its value

Comment: Wow Oktay, I really skipped this feature. Well, btw is it smart technique if all state values produced with useMemo and useRef ?

Comment: Or is useSelector settlings all the way ?

Comment: It is used as a closure hack. It does not matter where the value comes from